# zbar QR Code decode issue

Tags: c++, qt, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a qr code decoder in C++ for desktop purposes and wanted to use a batch file to execute zbar on windows to read the image.

It will be used with Qt and I wanted to know if I can change the output of the batch file to appear in a textEdit, I have already changed the standard output std::cout to appear in the textEdit and I thought that this would do the trick.

If there is not a way to make it appear directly is there a way that I can grab the result from the batch file and bring it back to my c++ program?

Here is the code I found online to test out changing std::cout:

main.cpp:

```
#include "qr.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include "qdebugstream.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.connect(&app,SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()),&app,SLOT(quit()));
    //QR w;
    //w.show();

    QMainWindow* mainWindow = new QMainWindow();

    QTextEdit* myTextEdit = new QTextEdit(mainWindow);
    myTextEdit->setReadOnly(true);
    QDebugStream qout(std::cout, myTextEdit);
    std::clog<<"hello";
    mainWindow->show();
    std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;
    //system("D:\\QRCode\\JQR_Gen\\Debug\\runZbar.bat");


    return app.exec();
}
```

qdebugstream.h:

```
 #ifndef QDEBUGSTREAM_H
#define QDEBUGSTREAM_H

#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>

#include "qtextedit.h"

class QDebugStream : public std::basic_streambuf<char>
{
public:
 QDebugStream(std::ostream &stream, QTextEdit* text_edit) : m_stream(stream)
 {
  log_window = text_edit;
  m_old_buf = stream.rdbuf();
  stream.rdbuf(this);
 }
 ~QDebugStream()
 {
  // output anything that is left
  if (!m_string.empty())
   log_window->append(m_string.c_str());

  m_stream.rdbuf(m_old_buf);
 }

protected:
 virtual int_type overflow(int_type v)
 {
  if (v == '\n')
  {
   log_window->append(m_string.c_str());
   m_string.erase(m_string.begin(), m_string.end());
  }
  else
   m_string += v;

  return v;
 }

 virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const char *p, std::streamsize n)
 {
  m_string.append(p, p + n);

  int pos = 0;
  while (pos != std::string::npos)
  {
   pos = m_string.find('\n');
   if (pos != std::string::npos)
   {
    std::string tmp(m_string.begin(), m_string.begin() + pos);
    log_window->append(tmp.c_str());
    m_string.erase(m_string.begin(), m_string.begin() + pos + 1);
   }
  }

  return n;
 }

private:
 std::ostream &m_stream;
 std::streambuf *m_old_buf;
 std::string m_string;


  QTextEdit* log_window;
    };

#endif
```

and here is the batch file code:

```
@set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\ZBar\bin
@cd D:\QRCode\JQR_Gen
@zbarimg "test.bmp"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, was hoping to do it this way as it seemed it would be a lot easier than using zbar properly within c++ as I read it doesn't have very good functionality on windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can run 'zbarimg "test.bmp"' with QProcess without using a batch file, and read the output using QProcess API.

Comment: I am following this http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html and I can't work out what needs to go into the program QString atm in order to run this command, atm I am just using the batch file, but you say that it can be done directly? Thanks for the quick reply before as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and not even compiled example of using QProcess.

```
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QProcess qCommandZbarimg;
   qCommandZbarimg.start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ZBar\\bin\\zbarimg.exe",
                          QStringList() << "Path\\To\\Bitmap\\test.bmp");
   // Wait only up to 2000 ms for successful termination of the command.
   if(qCommandZbarimg.waitForFinished(2000))
   {
      // Okay, "zbarimg.exe test.tmp" was executed successfully.
      // Read output of this command to stdout into an array of bytes.
      QByteArray qCommandOuput = qCommandZbarimg.readAll();
      qCommandZbarimg.close();
      // Has the command written anything to stdout?
      if(qCommandOuput.size() > 0)
      {
         // Do whatever you want to do with the output.
      }
   }
   // Dummy code to have no warnings on build.
   if(argv[0][1] == ' ') return argc;
   return 0;
}
```